# Show that if $f \in L^{1}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, $|f(x)| < \infty$ for a.e. $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to get through a proof of a theorem in Elias's book on real analysis, and part of it seems to rely on the fact that if $f \in L^{1}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, $|f(x)| < \infty$ for a.e. $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Why is that true, though? Can someone perhaps provide a proof? All I can see is why it would hold for every compact set, but why would it hold in general?

Comment: Because $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be covered with a countable union of compact sets.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, and therefore the countable union of the "infinity sets" within those compact sets would also have measure zero, because each of them does? Was that your argument?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thanks, I knew right away I was going to feel stupid, and I kind of thought it would be something like this, as well. Still, I wasn't quite clear in my thinking and wanted to make sure, just so that I don't just hand-wave myself into believing it.

Comment: That's a good policy, @Ryker, to confirm that what you think is indeed right.

Comment: @DanielFischer, yeah, that's my logic, as well. But sometimes I'm hesitant to post here, since I'm never quite sure whether a lot of questions on my part would then slowly lead to fewer answers due to people looking at my history and perhaps thinking I'm trying to find an easy way out for every question I have or thinking I'm masking up homework questions. But when I'm learning things, I sometimes just can't wait a couple of days to ask a professor or some other person who might know the answer and I really do try to think things through with frivolously asking right away.

Comment: @Ryker You can also drop into the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) and ask there in such cases. There are almost always enough people there that somebody can tell you "Yes, that's right" or "No, you overlooked xyz".

Comment: @DanielFischer, I haven't thought of that, although it seems this would only work for the more straight-forward statements, whereas when you need to elaborate on it, it might not be a good idea to ask there. But I'll definitely keep that in mind.